# Clarification of Proof Method

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Here is the proof in question: Prove that is $G$ is a group and $a,b \in G$ then $|ab|=|ba|$.

I found a solution that I am trying to understand here. What I do not understand is how one can go from $(ab)^n$ to $(ab)(ab)^n(ab)$. If somebody could provide clarification on why this is allowed I would appreciate it.

Comment: Hint:  $ba=b(ab)b^{-1}$.  Now show that inner automorphisms preserve order.

Comment: assuming $(ab)^n = e $, then of course $(ab)(ab) = (ab)e(ab) = (ab)(ab)^n(ab)$

Comment: thanks i got it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked answer does not "go" from $(ab)^n$ to $(ab)(ab)^n(ab)$. Rather, it (validly) uses that $x=y$ implies $uxv=uyv$ (here, with $x=(ab)^n$, $y=e$, $u=v=ab$).